# Should we have a V6 Specific Powershell Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Version 6 of Powershell is significantly different from every prior version. Unless I am completely missing it there is not currently a V6 specific tag. I believe that there should be one. The adoption at first I suspect will be spotty and often wrong, but as more people start using V6 I believe that it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you link a relevant question? I agree and could just create the tag.

Comment: I haven't been paying close attention, but I can't recall seeing _any_ questions specific to PowerShell version 6 yet. If we just aren't getting any questions, do we really need a tag?